# Using a method inside a key value pair to truncate a string

Tags: javascript, lodash, truncate, keyvaluepair

I am using the Lodash and jQuery library inside my javascript and I am trying to figure out how to call a method that will allow me to truncate the results of a key value pair used to create a list inside my .html code. The html looks as follows:

```
 <div class="slide-in-panel">
        <ul class="list-unstyled slide-in-menu-navigation" data-bind="foreach: __plugins">
            <li class="btn-block">
                <div class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-bind="click: $parent.showPlugin, tooltip: 'Shoebox.Panel'">
                    <span data-bind="text: config.title"></span>
                    <em class="webgis-Icon webgis-Cross slide-in-menu-remove-shoebox-button"
                        data-bind="click: $parent.showRemoveConfirmBox, tooltip: 'Shoebox.RemoveShoebox'">
                    </em>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

The key component is the `data-bind="text: config.title"` part. This populates the list with name for that button. The `config.title` is created in the javascript file below. My goal is to apply a method such as `.truncate()` to the `config.title` part in the javascript to keep whatever name is being populated, from being to long. How would I do this?

```
 return this.__backendShoeboxClient.createShoebox(this.__shoeboxName()).then((function(_this) {
      return function(shoebox) {
        return $when.join(shoebox.getName(), shoebox.getId(), shoebox.getUserName()).then(function(arg) {
          var shoeboxId, shoeboxName, userName;
          shoeboxName = arg[0], shoeboxId = arg[1], userName = arg[2];
          return _this.__shoeboxContentFactory.create({
            shoeboxId: shoeboxId,
            shoeboxName: shoeboxName,
            userName: userName
          }).then(function(arg1) {
            var activeShoeboxHandle, config, shoeboxContent;
            shoeboxContent = arg1.shoeboxContent, activeShoeboxHandle = arg1.activeShoeboxHandle;
            _this.__activeShoeboxHandleMain.loadModel(activeShoeboxHandle);
            config = {
              plugin: shoeboxContent,
              title: shoeboxName,
              userName: userName,
              id: shoeboxId,
              handle: activeShoeboxHandle,
              icon: ""
            };
            _this.add(config, null, null);
            activeShoeboxHandle.loadModel(shoebox);
            _this.__shoeboxName.useDefaultValue();
            return _this.__shoeboxName.clearError();
          });
        })["catch"](function(error) {
          __logger__.error("Error while calling request " + error);
          return $when.reject(new Error("Error while calling request. " + error));
        });
      };
    })(this));
  };
```

I am also trying to use the knockout `style` binding like this, but without any success:

```
<span data-bind="style: { textOverflow: ellipsis }, text: config.title"></span>
```

Comment: Are you trying to truncate `shoeboxName`?

Comment: That will work. Or `config.title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for edification's sake, I was able to find a solution to this problem using the substring method inside a simple if statement. The issue seemed to be that I was putting this in the wrong part of my code so I want to clarify what worked for me for future readers. I was able to apply the following inside the key: value pair and it totally worked:

```
config =
    plugin: shoeboxContent
    title: if name.length > 24
        "#{name.substring 0, 24}..."
    else
        name

    userName: shoebox.getUserName()
    id: shoebox.getId()
    handle: activeShoeboxHandle
    icon: ""

@add config, null, null
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:
Use the truncate function like this: config.title = _.truncate(config.title, {'length': maxLength});

```
return this.__backendShoeboxClient.createShoebox(this.__shoeboxName()).then((function(_this) {
  return function(shoebox) {
    return $when.join(shoebox.getName(), shoebox.getId(), shoebox.getUserName()).then(function(arg) {
      var shoeboxId, shoeboxName, userName;
      shoeboxName = arg[0], shoeboxId = arg[1], userName = arg[2];
      return _this.__shoeboxContentFactory.create({
        shoeboxId: shoeboxId,
        shoeboxName: shoeboxName,
        userName: userName
      }).then(function(arg1) {
        var activeShoeboxHandle, config, shoeboxContent;
        shoeboxContent = arg1.shoeboxContent, activeShoeboxHandle = arg1.activeShoeboxHandle;
        _this.__activeShoeboxHandleMain.loadModel(activeShoeboxHandle);
        config = {
          plugin: shoeboxContent,
          title: shoeboxName,
          userName: userName,
          id: shoeboxId,
          handle: activeShoeboxHandle,
          icon: ""
        };
        config.title = _.truncate(config.title, {'length': 15});
        _this.add(config, null, null);
        activeShoeboxHandle.loadModel(shoebox);
        _this.__shoeboxName.useDefaultValue();
        return _this.__shoeboxName.clearError();
      });
    })["catch"](function(error) {
      __logger__.error("Error while calling request " + error);
      return $when.reject(new Error("Error while calling request. " + error));
    });
  };
})(this));
```

};

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work. I am now trying to use the following, but it's not working either: `<span data-bind="style: { textOverflow: ellipsis }, text: config.title"></span>`

Comment: Sorry, the truncate method returns a string, it doesn't edit what you pass in. See my edit.